# Why doesn't mount wait for systemd.fsck to finish running?

Tags: systemd, mount, ubuntu-18.04, fstab

Whenever `systemd.fsck` actually has to do a repair* at boot time, automatic mounting of my partition fails because the `mount` command doesn't wait until `systemd.fsck@dev-sda1.service` is done.

How do I ensure that `mount` waits until the file system check service finishes instead of failing immediately because the file system check was started?

The relevant line in `fstab` looks like this:

```
LABEL=cfdata   /data   ext4  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=60     0 0
```

(the label `cfdata` is on `/dev/sda1`)

The relevant systemd logs look like this when there's a failed mount at boot:

```
Jun 23 06:24:45 dev-machine-1 kernel:  sda: sda1
Jun 23 06:24:45 dev-machine-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jun 23 06:24:47 dev-machine-1 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/sda1...
Jun 23 06:24:47 dev-machine-1 mount[5563]: mount: /data: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.
Jun 23 06:24:47 dev-machine-1 systemd-fsck[5483]: cfdata: recovering journal
Jun 23 06:24:49 dev-machine-1 systemd-fsck[5483]: cfdata: Clearing orphaned inode 13 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100644, size=39685)
Jun 23 06:24:49 dev-machine-1 systemd-fsck[5483]: cfdata: clean, 2767944/29310976 files, 75558004/117212630 blocks
Jun 23 06:24:49 dev-machine-1 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/sda1.
Jun 23 06:24:49 dev-machine-1 kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

When this happens, the drive gets mounted to `/media/<uuid>` instead of my mount point in `fstab`.

Note:
When `systemd.fsck@dev-sda1.service` has to do a repair, output in the journal will be something like: `Clearing orphaned inode 13 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100644, size=39685)`. The mount problem only happens when fsck is actually doing something like this and holds up the device.

Comment: Look at the appropriate unit file in `/run/systemd/generator/` to see if it has a `Requires=systemd-fsck@...` line or not and if this matches the fstab 6th field being 0 or not. If it is ending up in `/media` doesn't that mean it is  udisks2 that is doing a fsck-before-mount, so perhaps it is starting too soon somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your system to include it in the file system check list:

> ### The sixth field (fs_passno).
>
> This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the  order  in  which filesystem  checks  are  done at boot time. The root filesystemshould be specified with a fs_passno of  1. Other  filesystems should  have  a fs_passno of 2. Filesystems within a drive will be checked sequentially, but  filesystems on different  drives will  be  checked at the same time to utilize parallelism available in the hardware. Defaults to zero (don't fsck)  if not present.

(From `man fstab`)

Make the line read

```
LABEL=cfdata   /data   ext4  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=60     0 2
```

And it should be handled automatically.

Comment: Since I have it set to 0 now, wouldn't that mean fsck shouldn't run at all?

Comment: @StevenT.Snyder yes. But it will have to check the journal when mounting. But you will not have a full fsck.